# How do I create an equivalent to the collapsible panel extender in HTM file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side, collapsiblepanelextender

I created an asp.net file with a working collapsible panel.
I assumed that if I take the client side's source and copy it into an HTM file it would still work - but it doesn't.

What I did was "view source" and copied all of it to a blank HTM file.
All is working besides for the collapsible panel.

Why? Can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Here is Why

I will try and explain in short but have to use assumptions. ASP.NET is a web application framework that is compiled at runtime meaning your page is converted from objects and controls to html, css and javascript; the Javascript (ScriptResource.axd) is encrypted and you do not have access to the scripts in your htm page. [Good Link about ScriptResource.axd](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETAjaxScriptCombiningAndMovingScriptResourceaxdsToStaticScripts.aspx)

### How to fix it?

**The Great news is yes!** Assuming you are using AJAXToolKit (and yes that is a big assumption), you can instead use jQuery UI Accordion with only one section. I tested both and they work the same. I hope this helps! [jQuery Accordion reference](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#collapsible)

### ASPX Example using AJAX (Collapsible Panel):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender runat="server" 
        TargetControlID="Panel1" 
        Collapsed="true"
        ExpandControlID="LinkButton1" 
        CollapseControlID="LinkButton1" />

    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Panel</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        This is a Test
    </asp:Panel>
  </div>
</form>
```

### HTM Example using jQuery (Accordion):

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Panel1').hide();

        $('#pnlLink').click(function () {
            $(this).next().toggle();
            return false;
        }).next().hide();
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
   <a id="pnlLink" href="#">Panel</a>
   <div id="Panel1">
    <div>
        This is a test</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQueryUI accordion functionality
http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

or jQuery slideToggle() function
Regards
Nate